# Why my answer does not appear with 2 decimals?

Tags: java

I can't understand where's the problem and why my number does not become with 2 numbers in the end. Tried various examples, but still receiving an problem.

```
public double apskaiciuotiKainaUzLitra(int kaina, int talpa) {
        double kainaLitro = (1000 / talpa) * kaina;
        double roundOff = Math.round(kainaLitro * 100.0) / 100.0;
        return roundOff;
    }
```

Comment: 'Still receiving an problem' I mean that my number is still with 1 number in the end.

Comment: Can you add the current output of your code and your desired output?

Comment: Did you use integer division here intentionally? 1000 / talpa? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/1288408

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.format()` to format

```
public double apskaiciuotiKainaUzLitra(int kaina, int talpa) {
        double kainaLitro = (1000 / talpa) * kaina;
        double roundOff = Math.round(kainaLitro * 100.0) / 100.0;
        return new Double(String.format( "%.2f", roundOff));
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this code have a mismatch between the declared return type and the actual returned type?

Comment: It should not work. The method returns double whereas this code is returning a String.

Comment: @mrbolichi edited.

Comment: @Parth updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

After doing that, you can use formatter.